# Grouping large set of similar vectors

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I have a 3d mesh of ~200,000 triangles.

To find all the flat (or near enough flat) surfaces on the model I thought I could try and group triangles by their normal vectors (giving me ones which face the same way) and then I can search these smaller sets for ones which are similar in position or connected.

I cannot think of a good way to practically do this while also keeping things relatively speedy. I have come up with solutions which would take n² but none which are elegant and quicker than that.

I have vertex information and triangle information (vertices, centre and normal).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are meshing with code that you have the sources, then annotate the triangle (at its creation) if its normal is near-vertical.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that I have misunderstood the problem so I am stating what I think you need to do : *"Given a set of vectors, group parallel vectors together"*.

You could use a hash-map to solve this problem. I am assuming that you stored the normal vectors in the form:

**a**[image] + **b**[image] + **c**[image] = **0**

You just need to write a function that converts a vector to an integer, for example, if I know that **0 <= a, b, c <= 1000**, then I can use **F(a, b, c) = a + 1000b + 1000000c** which guarantees unique integer for every unique vector. After this, its just a matter of creating a hashmap which maps some integer to a list and store all the parallel vectors in the same list.

Comment: This doesn't work with *near enough flat surfaces*.

Comment: @Yola I missed the "near enough flat" part. I am having trouble with understanding how a nearly flat surface would be defined. The way I see it, a set of vector can have multiple possible answers if we go looking for nearly flat surfaces. How would you define it?

Comment: Probably normals are computed from the corresponding triangles, and there will be some floating point errors. If this is true, then, probably, it is possible to fix it first.

Comment: So what we want to do is group together equal vectors within some tolerance. This make the problem somewhat complicated. Let 2% be the permissible error. Suppose vectors A and B are equal with an error of 2% and, B and C with an error of 2%, we have to make sure that A and C are also within this 2% error. This will have to be an O(n^2) algo then

Answer (score 0):

You want to find connected components on the graph from your triangles. The only thing you need is to store adjacency information in a convenient form.

Create a list of all edges `(min, max)`, if all edges have two triangles adjacent, then there are 300'000 edges. This can be done in linear time:

1. For every vertex count number of adjacent vertices with greater index, do the partial sum on these numbers.
2. Allocate and fill an array for edges (second vertex and utility data). Use array from step 1 to access edges adjacent to a vertex. Such an access can be done in the constant time if we know that the number of edges adjacent to a vertex is bounded from above by a constant and the whole step can be done in the linear time.

So, mentioned utility data is the numbers of pair of triangles adjacent to the edge.

Ok, now you have adjacency info. It is time to find connected components. You can use DFS for it. It will work in the linear time because every triangle has three (constant number of) neighbors.

Here you need to allocate `200'000 * sizeof(int) * 4` bytes. And it can be done in the linear time.

---

You could also want to read about [doubly connected edge list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list), but it is pretty expensive.